# In knockout how to check if an element is present or not in a json and render UI

Tags: knockout.js

My JSON is as follows

```
        ko.applyBindings({
        planets: [
            { name: 'Mercury' },
            { name: 'Earth', capital: { cityName: 'Barnsley' } }
        ]


    });
```

Using this JSON and Knockout, i want the UI to display as below

NoCaptial : Planet Mercury

Capital  Barnsley : Earth

Basically as Mercy doesnot have Capital field , it should display NoCaptial.

I tried the following,

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: planets">
<li>

    <div data-bind="if: capital">
        Capital: <b data-bind="text: capital.cityName"> </b>
    </div>
    Planet: <b data-bind="text: name"> </b>
</li>
```

How to check if Capital is not present.

Comment: Show your view model.

Comment: @DavidTansey: i updated the Question for showing the VIEW MODEL

Comment: This is the example 2 from the knockout site: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html. Are you saying this example doesn't work?

Comment: @mhu: i have modified the same example according to our requirement. inthe knockout example , you have "capital: null" for "Mercury", but in my example its not at all present. I have took the example just for simplicity

Comment: so mean to say you don't have capital property itself ? and you want to handle it ? correct me

Comment: @supercool: yes, you are right, we dont have capital property itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the 'capital' property is set (and provide an alternative String in case it's not) like this:

```
    <div>
        Capital: <b data-bind="text: $data.capital ? $data.capital.cityName : 'NoCapital'"> </b>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ifnot:` or `if: !` binding for this: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/ifnot-binding.html

Example:

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: capital">
    NoCapital
</div>
```

As *CrimsonChris* says, you can use `$data` when not all properties exist in your model:

```
<div data-bind="ifnot: $data.capital">
    NoCapital
</div>
```

Comment: this code works only if you have "Capital: null" in your viewmodel. my question was more to do if we dont have it atall in my viewmodel for Mercury

Comment: If capital is an "optional" property in your view model, use $data.capital

Comment: @CrimsonChris i agree and you can also try using `with` which is safe .